# c# with Assembler dll

Tags: c#, arrays, string, assembly, dll

I write program using assembler dll and trying to add function from assembler to my c# program which will return amount of chars in my string from c#.

c# program:

```
[DllImport("bibliotekaASM.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int zlicz(string tab);

 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             int pom=0;
            string tab = "1111111fdgsdgdgd";

            pom = zlicz(tab);


        }
```

and my assembler code:

```
myprocedure proc 


push ebp
mov  ebp, esp

mov  ebx, [ebp+8]           ; begin of char array

xor eax, eax

check:

cmp byte ptr[ebx],0    ; if end of array 
je endprocedure
inc ebx
inc eax 
jmp check
endprocedure:    

pop ebp

ret 

myprocedure endp
```

but it works only for string with more than 100 elements for example 7 element this program crashing with error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in GUI.exe

Can someone help me with this problem because I want to use strings with less than 100 elements.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure how it works at *all*.  Your assemby code seems to be expecting a C string (array of null-terminated ASCII bytes), not a C#/.Net "string" object type.  Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22e4dash.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic link library expects a null terminated ansi string, and you are passing a length prefixed BSTR

According to the [MSDN documentation, Default Marshaling for Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx), the following signature:

```
DllImport("bibliotekaASM.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int myprocedure(string tab);
```

will marshal the string variable tab as `UnmanagedType.BStr`

According to this table though:

```
UnmanagedType.BStr (default)
    A COM-style BSTR with a prefixed length and Unicode characters.  
UnmanagedType.LPStr
    A pointer to a null-terminated array of ANSI characters.  
UnmanagedType.LPWStr
    A pointer to a null-terminated array of Unicode characters.
```

what you need is to Marshal the tab variable as `UnmanagedType.LPStr`

This can be easily achieved by:

```
DllImport("bibliotekaASM.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int myprocedure([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string tab);
```

However,

This will marshal the string as one byte per character, meaning, you are passing an ANSI string, and not supporting unicode.

To support unicode characters, simply change the unmanaged type specification to `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`

```
DllImport("bibliotekaASM.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int myprocedure([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string tab);
```

In this case however, you should also update the assembler code to read unicode characters (which I can imagine is not a simple task)

Note: I reproduced the issue by compiling the dll using MASM32 and by invoking it from C# and tested the proposed solution LPStr with success.

Comment: Thank you for help but still it does not work. add [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] didnt make difference and still it doesnt work for strings less than 128 elements. Did you change some registers in asm code? I dont know what is going on ;/

Comment: But it's working on my machine. Can you please also share the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Because I don't get 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in GUI.exe, I just get an exception, access violation (0x0000005) when tried your way.

Comment: my procedure works perfectly but this exception occure after ret in asm procedure. in EAX is correct number of elements in string

Comment: No stack trace? Do details?

Comment: before ret in eax is correct amount of elements and then after ret i just get this http://iv.pl/images/21290668888041490245.png

Comment: If you click break, it should give you more information in a window like the quick watch. I am going to try this myself in a windows forms app, I tried it only with a console app so far.